# @prompt in Business Objects, how can use dynamic data or list

Tags: prompt, business-objects

I'm new to BO, i want to prompt the report user to **select multiple items from a list** before generating the report.
the list is dynamic and it should read from a (look up) table in DB.
i tried to use ***@prompt*** function but cant do it. 
one more thing, i want the user to be able to filter the data in browser

regards!

Comment: Yes it is technically feasible. [Please see this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15889149/business-objects-xi-web-intelligence-how-to-reference-a-list-of-measures-as-vari)

Comment: What you're describing is basic prompt functionality -- what did you use for your @Prompt, and what problem did you have with it?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using @prompt, you can try like this.

In Modify(Design) Mode, go to Data Access --> Edit.

There in filter bar, drag the Object that you want to appear as Prompt for the user, say Year. Select "In List" and change it to a Prompt by selecting the Prompt option from "define filter type" which is available at the end of the filter object selected.

hope this helps you to resolve.